# Whats error in this code

Tags: java, multithreading, extends

```
class thread123 extends Thread {

    public thread123(int ind, int interval) {
        i0 = ind;
        delay = interval;
    }

    public void run() {

        try {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                if (i0 == 1) {
                    System.out.println("n = " + i + ", Time = " + (delay * i - delay) + ", Thread one: " + (2 * i + 5));
                } else if (i0 = 2) {
                    System.out.println("n = " + i + ", Time = " + (delay * i - delay) + ", Thread Two: " + (i + 10) * 2);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("n = " + i + ", Time = " + (delay * i - delay) + ", Thread Three: " + (18 * (i * i) - 12) / (i - 2);
                }
                sleep(delay);
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        }

    }

    private int i0;
}

class Threads {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        thread123 t1 = new thread123(1, 20);
        thread123 t2 = new thread123(2, 3.0);
        thread123 t3 = new thread123(3, 40);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
        System.out.println("Main thread done");
    }

}
```

Comment: A code dump does not make a question.  Can you explain what your expected results are and what you actual result are?

Comment: `} else if (i0 = 2) {` looks suspicious

Answer (score 1):

- `thread123 t2 = new thread123(2, 3.0);` is invalid, because `thread123` only takes `int`s
- `delay = interval;` is invalid as `delay` is undefined, so anything to do with `delay` is related to this
- `} else if (i0 = 2) {` is and assignment, not an assessment, which doesn't equate to a `boolean`, so that's invalid
- `System.out.println("n = " + i + ", Time = " + (delay * i - delay) + ", Thread Three: " + (18 * (i * i) - 12) / (i - 2);` is missing a closing `)`

You might also like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others